# condition on the sequence of values after groupby using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I searched google and stackoverflow to find the right way to a filtering based on each group and sequence of conditions. Could't find any!
I have a tracking dataset in pandas, I want to filter those users that initiate signup and did successfully sign in. Data looks like the below:

```
   user_id        event                   time
     1             signupinitiated         2019-07-14 08:36:38.004
     1             other event             2019-07-14 08:37:38.004
     2             signupinitiated         2019-07-14 06:10:40.004 
     2             signupsuccess           2019-07-14 06:10:45.004
```

I only want to have user 2 in my final dataframe. I wrote the below code which doesn't take into account the user_id group.

```
 s = df.eq('signupinitiated').any(1) & df.shift(-1).eq('signupsuccess').any(1)
df_si_ss=df[s | s.shift()]
```

Any idea how to apply this condition for each user_id group?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since 'signupsuccess' is not possible without 'signupinitiated', how about filtering the dataframe after groupby? The code below will keep 'user_id' 2 in the df given above.

```
df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: (x['event'] == 'signupsuccess').any())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby with transform then boolean indexing:

```
df[df.groupby('user_id')['event']\
  .transform(lambda x: ((x  == "signupinitiated") & 
                    (x.shift(-1) == 'signupsuccess')).max())]
```

Output:

```
   user_id            event                     time
2        2  signupinitiated  2019-07-14 06:10:40.004
3        2    signupsuccess  2019-07-14 06:10:45.004
```